# Java - Using multiple delimiters in a scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm using a scanner to take input and, hopefully, split it into chunks. I want it to split it up using whole word delimiters. So right now I have:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1 imported bottle of perfume at 27.99");
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\sdelimitOne\\s");
```

So with input "word word delimitOne word word delimitTwo word word" I get output:

```
word word
word word delimitTwo word word
```

I was hoping

```
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\sdelimitOne\\s\\sdelimitTwo\\s");
```

might work, but alas not.

How do I go about achieving the following output:

```
word word
word word
word word
```

?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From wikipedia :

> | : The choice (aka alternation or set union) operator matches either the expression before or the expression after the operator. For example, abc|def matches "abc" or "def".

so, `scanner.useDelimiter("\\sdelimitOne\\s|\\sdelimitTwo\\s");` is what you need.

Comment: Ah fantastic, I was hoping it would be some such silly omission. Thanks very much.